# How to confirm text, that is displayed twice on the same web page, in JMeter with an assertion

Tags: jmeter

I have a Response Assertion to check for the word "this" on a web page.  But, the word "this" appears more than once on this web page.  How can I confirm that it is shown multiple times on this web page?  To throw a wrench in it, the word "this" appears in a banner on the web page and then again in what would be considered the main body of the web page.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of doing this is to use regular expression in the assertion:

```
    this([\s\S]*)this
```

and set the patterns matching rule to "Matches".
The matching pattern allows to match even across multiple lines.

The assertion is true if the word is repeated at least 2 times.

However, this is far from being efficient: I would try to look for more typical words that appears in your text.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will try this.  Also, could you vote up my question if you think it is a worthy one.  I have been waiting patiently, asking legitimate questions ( if you check my account ), but it is very hard to get reputation on this site if you do not have very much to begin with.